# Reorganize chain

Tags: block, bitcoinj

BitcoinJ:

1. Is is possible to get somehow transactions from ReorganizeListener in block chain? I'm able to get list of new blocks which are represented by StoredBlock but from StoredBlock I can't get any transaction.
2. Is BlocksDownloadedEventListener will also trigger for new blocks after split? I want to know if any new block from split point will also trigger BlocksDownloadedEventListener.

Thanks for help :)